Fetching Trending Token Data: How to Access via API from Dexscreener or Birdeye
I'm trying to gather data on currently trending tokens, and I've been exploring options like Dexscreener and Birdeye. Unfortunately, I haven't found a direct way to access this information via their APIs.
Does anyone know how to retrieve data about trending tokens from these platforms, or if there another API that provides similar information? I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to programmatically fetch details about the most popular tokens at any given time.
Any guidance or alternative recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
These are the dexscreener criteria for tokens in trading but I don't see any API to call them : https://docs.dexscreener.com/trending
Thank you!

You can access trending token data from Birdeye via their API. Birdeye provides an API endpoint specifically for interacting with trending tokens. You can find the documentation for this endpoint here: Birdeye API - Get DeFi Token List.
Birdeye's API allows you to programmatically fetch details about the most popular tokens at any given time, providing a straightforward way to gather this information.
For Dexscreener, there currently isn't a direct API endpoint to fetch trending tokens as per their documentation. You might need to manually scrape the website or look for alternative APIs that provide similar information.
